# PyTorch nn.Transformer learns to copy target

Tags: pytorch, transformer-model

I’m trying to train a Transformer Seq2Seq model using nn.Transformer class. I believe I am implementing it wrong, since when I train it, it seems to fit too fast, and during inference it repeats itself often. This seems like a masking issue in the decoder, and when I remove the target mask, the training performance is the same. This leads me to believe I am doing the target masking wrong. Here is my model code:

```
class TransformerModel(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, 
        vocab_size, input_dim, heads, feedforward_dim, encoder_layers, decoder_layers, 
        sos_token, eos_token, pad_token, max_len=200, dropout=0.5, 
        device=(torch.device("cuda") if torch.cuda.is_available() else torch.device("cpu"))):

        super(TransformerModel, self).__init__()
        self.target_mask = None
        self.embedding = nn.Embedding(vocab_size, input_dim, padding_idx=pad_token)
        self.pos_embedding = nn.Embedding(max_len, input_dim, padding_idx=pad_token)
        self.transformer = nn.Transformer(
            d_model=input_dim, nhead=heads, num_encoder_layers=encoder_layers, 
            num_decoder_layers=decoder_layers, dim_feedforward=feedforward_dim, 
            dropout=dropout)
        self.out = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Linear(input_dim, feedforward_dim), 
            nn.ReLU(), 
            nn.Linear(feedforward_dim, vocab_size))

        self.device = device
        self.max_len = max_len
        self.sos_token = sos_token
        self.eos_token = eos_token

    # Initialize all weights to be uniformly distributed between -initrange and initrange
    def init_weights(self): 
        initrange = 0.1
        self.encoder.weight.data.uniform_(-initrange, initrange)
        self.decoder.bias.data.zero_()
        self.decoder.weight.data.uniform_(-initrange, initrange)

    # Generate mask covering the top right triangle of a matrix
    def generate_square_subsequent_mask(self, size): 
        mask = (torch.triu(torch.ones(size, size)) == 1).transpose(0, 1)
        mask = mask.float().masked_fill(mask == 0, float('-inf')).masked_fill(mask == 1, float(0.0))
        return mask

    def forward(self, src, tgt):
        # src: (Max source seq len, batch size, 1)
        # tgt: (Max target seq len, batch size, 1)

        # Embed source and target with normal and positional embeddings
        embedded_src = (self.embedding(src) + 
           self.pos_embedding(
           torch.arange(0, src.shape[1]).to(self.device).unsqueeze(0).repeat(src.shape[0], 1)))
        # Generate target mask
        target_mask = self.generate_square_subsequent_mask(size=tgt.shape[0]).to(self.device) 
        embedded_tgt = (self.embedding(tgt) + 
            self.pos_embedding(
            torch.arange(0, tgt.shape[1]).to(self.device).unsqueeze(0).repeat(tgt.shape[0], 1)))
        # Feed through model
        outputs = self.transformer(src=embedded_src, tgt=embedded_tgt, tgt_mask=target_mask)
        outputs = F.log_softmax(self.out(outputs), dim=-1)
        return outputs
```

Comment: Try posting this in the pytorch forum instead? Very interested to know whats going on

Comment: I've figured out my problem, I wasn't using the SOS and EOS tokens in the right place, so the target was not offset by 1, so it was able to copy the given target directly to the output, no matter the mask

Comment: You should probably answer your own question then, to mark it as solved, it could help :)

Answer (score 2):

For those having the same problem, my issue was that I wasn't properly adding the SOS token to the target I was feeding the model, and the EOS token to the target I was using in the loss function.

For reference:
The target fed to the model should be: [SOS] ....

And the target used for the loss should be: .... [EOS]